# How to extract time and other information as key value pair in log file

Tags: parsing, logging

Requirement-: user can do search of alarms , error  based on time in below trace

I have below mentioned very unstructured log trace where need to extract time and other information as key value so that same can be inserted into elastic search or redis db . basically whereever time information is coming that should be considered as key and next information before next time as value.

Expected key and value example are .

key1-:
2023/07/21 18:11:05.821
value1-:
TRACE HIGH  aim:2922 E:20460350 S:6591567 (service.c 141 V-ipds0 CMM21.0.0.5 cmmman 169.254.64.60)

key2 -:
2023/07/21 18:11:19.633
value2-:
ALARM HIGHEST pmCollector:32045 E:35687149 S:786225 (PfmCpiElement.cpp 2363 V-necc0  169.254.64.30)

Alarm Class     : pm                    Event = 15968
Alarm Severity  : cleared
Problem Type    : switchHealth
Alarm Name      : cpiCreateDedicatedBearerFailures
Reporting Obj   : Machine=SOTAVAM-CMM-01-necc0:PoolType=NECC:PoolId=0:PoolMemberId=0:Task=OSAB
Resource        : PoolType=CPPS:PoolId=0:PoolMemberId=0:CompId=PMCPI:Resource_type=cpiCreateDedicatedBearerFailures:UUID=240a6c52-5cb8-45f3-95fb-3bb3097dfdb5
Additional Info :

...................................................................................

log as below

Received unexpected cmd 4 sent from necc-0-0

**+++ 2023/07/21 18:1**1:05.434 TRACE HIGH ACTIVE ipds:3516 E:643694162 S:43809665 (cfgAppIntfc.cpp 1210 V-ipds0 CMM21.0.0.5 cmmman 169.254.64.60)

INFO:MME-CFGDBIM-2:CFGDBIMregisterWork: Send Task Register for table: table=wmm_service_pools, taskId=119

+++ 2023/07/21 18:11:05.821 TRACE HIGH  aim:2922 E:20460350 S:6591567 (service.c 141 V-ipds0 CMM21.0.0.5 cmmman 169.254.64.60)

Received unexpected cmd 4 sent from necc-0-0

+++ 2023/07/21 18:11:05.835 TRACE HIGH  aim:2914 E:20460308 S:6591540 (service.c 141 V-ipds1 CMM21.0.0.5 cmmman 169.254.64.61)

Received unexpected cmd 4 sent from necc-0-1

+++ 2023/07/21 18:11:05.871 TRACE HIGH  aim:2922 E:20460351 S:6591568 (service.c 141 V-ipds0 CMM21.0.0.5 cmmman 169.254.64.60)

Received unexpected cmd 4 sent from necc-0-0

+++ 2023/07/21 18:11:05.922 TRACE HIGH  aim:2922 E:20460352 S:6591569 (service.c 141 V-ipds0 CMM21.0.0.5 cmmman 169.254.64.60)

Received unexpected cmd 4 sent from necc-0-0

+++ 2023/07/21 18:11:05.887 TRACE HIGH  aim:2914 E:20460309 S:6591541 (service.c 141 V-ipds1 CMM21.0.0.5 cmmman 169.254.64.61)

Received unexpected cmd 4 sent from necc-0-1

+++ 2023/07/21 18:11:05.938 TRACE HIGH  aim:2914 E:20460310 S:6591542 (service.c 141 V-ipds1 CMM21.0.0.5 cmmman 169.254.64.61)

Received unexpected cmd 4 sent from necc-0-1

+++ 2023/07/21 18:11:06.874 TRACE HIGH ACTIVE dbs:2016 E:138921023 S:8856143 (DBScxnmtce.cpp 2142 V-dbs0 CMM21.0.0.5 cmmman 169.254.64.50)

INFO:MME-DBSCXNMT-30:DBShandleCountsAudit: Finished Counts Audit Cycle [ 196 ]; audited_total [ 4 ]

+++ 2023/07/21 18:11:06.874 TRACE HIGH ACTIVE dbs:2016 E:138921024 S:8856144 (DBSsub.cpp 3574 V-dbs0 CMM21.0.0.5 cmmman 169.254.64.50)

INFO:MME-DBSSUB-2: Counts Audit Summary
cppsCount: 4              cppsAuditCount: 4
mmeUnclaimedCount: 0      mmeUnclaimedAuditCount: 0
amfUnclaimedCount: 0      amfUnclaimedAuditCount: 0
papsCount: 0              papsAuditCount: 0

+++ 2023/07/21 18:11:07.211 TRACE HIGH ACTIVE cpps:2069 E:741585715 S:9957716 (ENBPXY.cpp 5783 V-cpps0 CMM21.0.0.5 cmmman 169.254.64.10)

INFO:MME-ENB-PXY:ENBPXY::erabSetupRsp:  vlrIdx=6, mgrId=6, cxnIdx=1, Failed E-RAB ID=8, cause=28

+++ 2023/07/21 18:11:07.211 TRACE HIGH ACTIVE cpps:2069 E:741585716 S:9957717 (BSMtauUtil.cpp 1192 V-cpps0 CMM21.0.0.5 cmmman 169.254.64.10)

ERROR:MME-BSM-MGR-7:BSM::isDfltBrr:  vlrIdx=6, mgrId=6, cxnIdx=1, getLbi failed for ebi = 8. VLRindex = 6

+++ 2023/07/21 18:11:16.997 TRACE HIGH ACTIVE dbs:2016 E:138921037 S:8856145 (DBScxnmtce.cpp 2072 V-dbs0 CMM21.0.0.5 cmmman 169.254.64.50)

INFO:MME-DBSCXNMT-30:DBShandleCountsAudit: Started Counts Audit Cycle [ 197 ]

+++ 2023/07/21 18:11:19.633 ALARM HIGHEST pmCollector:32045 E:35687149 S:786225 (PfmCpiElement.cpp 2363 V-necc0  169.254.64.30)

Alarm Class     : pm                    Event = 15968
Alarm Severity  : cleared
Problem Type    : switchHealth
Alarm Name      : cpiCreateDedicatedBearerFailures
Reporting Obj   : Machine=SOTAVAM-CMM-01-necc0:PoolType=NECC:PoolId=0:PoolMemberId=0:Task=OSAB
Resource        : PoolType=CPPS:PoolId=0:PoolMemberId=0:CompId=PMCPI:Resource_type=cpiCreateDedicatedBearerFailures:UUID=240a6c52-5cb8-45f3-95fb-3bb3097dfdb5
Additional Info :

+++ 2023/07/21 18:11:19.633 PERF_MGMT HIGH pmCollector:32045 E:35687148 S:786224 (PfmJobScheduler.cpp 732 V-necc0  169.254.64.30)

PFM_JobScheduler::processAllJobs() calling PFM_CpiElement::checkAlarm()

+++ 2023/07/21 18:11:21.212 TRACE HIGH ACTIVE cpps:2069 E:741585746 S:9957718 (ENBPXY.cpp 5783 V-cpps0 CMM21.0.0.5 cmmman 169.254.64.10)

INFO:MME-ENB-PXY:ENBPXY::erabSetupRsp:  vlrIdx=49359, mgrId=7, cxnIdx=1, Failed E-RAB ID=7, cause=28

there are mutiple such logs in gb to parse . is there any open source or any library to meet this requirment .